# mlogit and clusterSEs - error in dataframe

Tags: r, standard-error, mlogit

I have a dataset with multiple observations per customer and want to do a multinominal regression in R. To account for the multiple observations per customer, I need to check for clustered standard errors.

To do this I use the `mlogit` and `clusterSEs` package.

My first step was to transfer my original dataframe into a wide one:

```
mlMASTER_DATA <- mlogit.data(MASTER_DATA, shape = "wide", choice="Booking_status")
```

After that I created my model:

```
mnlModel_P3 <- mlogit(Booking_status ~ 1 | logprevious_bookings + logsearches,
                      data=mlMASTER_DATA, reflevel = "is_booked_24h", na.action = na.exclude)
```

The model runs normally.

In a third step, I want to account for standard errors:

```
Cluster_model <- cluster.im.mlogit(mnlModel_P3, mlMASTER_DATA, ~user_id)
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
error in `[.data.frame`(as.data.frame(x), i, j, drop = drop) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Can anybody help on this issue?
Many thanks!!

Comment: Usually it means that you are trying to select a variable that doesnt' exist in the data. If `mlogit.data` drops the `user_id` index when transforming the data, then it will not be available to the `cluster.im.mlogit` function when calling the transformed data. But for robust standard errors, you might be able to use a sandwich estimator. Look at the `sandwich` package. You can easily create the bread and the meat using the variance covariance matrix returned by `mlogit`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert your data.frame using the [dfidx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dfidx/vignettes/dfidx.html) package, which embeds an index with observation and cluster details into your data frame, before using cluster.im.logit().

For an example, first run `help(cluster.im.logit)`, then in the help quadrant scroll to bottom and look at the examples.

Here's the one I would start with:

```
H.ml <- dfidx(H, shape="wide", choice="depvar", varying=c(3:12), 
                idx = list(c("idcase", "region")))
```

This pivots the H df to wide format but also includes an idx column. idx is really a two-part index by observation and cluster (as I understand it). You can then run your mlogit with this new df:

```
m <- mlogit(depvar~ic+oc, H.ml)
```

Next run cluster.im.logit() on the model output and df with your specified cluster (which is embedded in idx). Per the help file again:

```
cluster.im.h <- cluster.im.mlogit(m, H.ml, ~ region)
```

Comment: Please can you update the answer and provide an example from the help file

Comment: Thanks for the prod. Just updated. Pretty new to this.

Comment: No worries :) - was in my review queue and want to make Stackoverflow great for everyone :)